# Link to a PGP/ASC-File on my website

Tags: pgp

I would like to include a link to a pgp key (asc-file) on my website, and if someone clicks it, I want it to open in the browser window (instead of displaying a download prompt). How can I do that? I tried the mime type mentioned on the following page, but it doesn't seem to work. http://www.bauser.com/websnob/keydist

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webmastering, not programming.

Comment: Eugene, I first asked my question in webmasters.stackexchange.com, but they said I have to post it here.

Comment: That's an unfortunate situation, but it's not related to programming *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to my .htaccess file seems to solve the problem.

```
AddType text/plain asc
```

It may not be the best solution, but it works for now.